Using apache mod_slotmem_shm module for caching in C
I am currently working on a Proof of Concept (POC) project where I aim to utilize Apache's **mod_slotmem_shm ** module for caching data in the shared memory of Apache and subsequently accessing this cached data across all Apache workers. However, I have encountered some challenges and would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving them.
Specifically, I am attempting to implement the functionalities described in the mod_slotmem_shm documentation found at the following link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_slotmem_shm.html
My objective is to create a POC that demonstrates the effective caching of data within Apache shared memory and its retrieval across multiple Apache worker processes.
I have already reviewed the documentation provided by Apache, but I am facing difficulties in correctly implementing the functionality in my environment.
Below are some specific areas where I am seeking assistance:

Initialization and configuration of mod_slotmem_shm within Apache.
Writing code to cache data in the shared memory using mod_slotmem_shm.
Retrieving cached data from the shared memory across multiple Apache worker processes.

If any of you have experience or expertise in working with mod_slotmem_shm or have implemented similar solutions in the past, I would greatly appreciate any guidance, code examples, or best practices that you can share.
Additionally, if there are any specific configurations, considerations, or potential pitfalls that I should be aware of when working with mod_slotmem_shm, I would be grateful for your insights.
I tried to find some code example in google search could not find find any clue specificllay how to use a apache module's function in my applictaion code and how to test it is working.
